# Showing value of 1 in ggplot2 bar graph with log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting frequency data (pre-counted) as a log-scale bar chart with ggplot2.  However, I have a value of 1, and it's just showing up as an empty bar in the result.  How do I make the bar chart include a bar for the value of 1?

Data:

```
NumLabels,NumInstances
1,411697
2,37899
3,6843
4,3319
5,1157
6,376
7,124
8,46
9,19
10,3
11,2
13,1
```

Plotting code:

```
datamatr <- read.csv('data.csv', header=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(
    NumLabels = factor(datamatr$NumLabels),
    NumInstances = datamatr$NumInstances
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=NumLabels,
               y=NumInstances))
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill='blue') +
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(-1,0,1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000),
              labels=trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
xlab('# of labels') +
ylab('# of instances') +
ggtitle('Distribution of labels') +
theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: From `help("geom_bar")`: "A bar chart maps the height of the bar to a variable, and so the base of the bar must always be shown to produce a valid visual comparison. Naomi Robbins has a nice article on this topic. This is why it doesn't make sense to use a log-scaled y axis with a bar chart." Make a dot plot instead.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it.

```
> log10(1)
[1] 0
```

In plain English, log_10 of 1 is 0. What you're (not) seeing is correct.

In addition, it's unlikely that you'll be able to visualize a very small value in a range that you have (10^5 and more).

Comment: Thanks, but what I was hoping was that I could tweak the axis in such a way that it could look like it starts at 0, so 10^0 would be rendered as a bar.  I can just smooth it by adding 0.1 or the like to avoid the fact that 0 is impossible on a logarithmic scale, but I'd prefer an exact solution if possible.

Comment: Tweaking the axis will distort the perceived proportions of the bars, so I would not do that. Isn't just adding a `geom_point()` an option?

Comment: @denbro42 another option is to include in the caption that for 13, number of labels is 1, but visualized as zero because of log_10 transformation.